# Correct way to handle CosmosDb FeedResponse<T> from a feed iterator?

Tags: .net, azure-cosmosdb

What is the correct way to handle CosmosDb FeedResponse from a feed iterator?

The documentation from the dotnet sdk has this example:

```
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition("select c.id From c where c.status = @status")
              .WithParameter("@status", "Failure");
using (FeedIterator<MyItem> feedIterator = this.Container.GetItemQueryIterator<MyItem>(
    queryDefinition))
{
    while (feedIterator.HasMoreResults)
    {
        FeedResponse<MyItem> response = await feedIterator.ReadNextAsync();
        foreach (var item in response)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
    }
}
```

But the example does not take the `response.StatusCode` and it doesn't seem like the `feedITerator.ReadNextAsync()` will throw any exceptions according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.feediterator-1.readnextasync?view=azure-dotnet).

So I would assume that I should take the `StatusCode` into consideration when getting a feed iterator response. It could for example return 500 if the connection to the DB is bad or 429  if I used the allocated read units. There are probably many other cases where the status code would not be 200.

Any suggestions or references to some documentation that shows hot to handle the response?

Comment: `StatusCode` doesn't return 500 or 429 it only returns for success scenarios. For more information, please check this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.response-1.statuscode?view=azure-dotnet#microsoft-azure-cosmos-response-1-statuscode).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding your own logic should not be necessary. The SDK has a retry policy by default that will [automatically retry known transient errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/conceptual-resilient-sdk-applications#should-my-application-retry-on-errors).

If you want to fine-tune it you can use the [CosmosClientOptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.cosmosclientoptions?view=azure-dotnet) and adjust the properties such as the `MaxRetryAttemptsOnRateLimitedRequests` and `MaxRetryWaitTimeOnRateLimitedRequests` should the default values not suit your case.

Comment: It it also the case when creatning items with CreateItemAsync(...)?

Comment: Yes. It applies to all standard CRUD operations the SDK provides.

Comment: Thank you so much. Transactional batches too? In the examples I see it seems like they use the IsSuccessStatusCode property, but only to get results from the transaction. Not to check if something went wrong. So if I don't care about the transaction results I could just ignore the IsSuccessStatusCode and assume everything is fine in an exception is not thrown?

Comment: @SimonK For the batch you'll still need to check the statuscode from the response. Unlike other methods it won't throw a `CosmosException`. You don't have to implement your own retry mechanism though.

Answer (score 2):

All typed APIS (anything with `<T>`) throw exceptions on failure: https://github.com/Azure/azure-cosmos-dotnet-v3/blob/master/Exceptions.md

You do not need to check if the response was successful in the case of `FeedIterator<T>`. If it's not, it will throw a `CosmosException`.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the documentation. Very helpfull.